# find column names and metadata from select query without executing the query

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a scenario, where the user will provide a Select statement. I need to find out the columns (their names, type, and other metadata), but I do not want to execute the query.
I know that I can execute the query and figure it from the `ResultSet`, but if the query returns many rows, then it may not be a good approach.

For example, consider the query

```
select name, age from people where people.dob = '1976';
```

Is there a way of getting the projected column metadata (i.e. metadata of name and age columns) without executing the query?

Comment: The only way I know of would be to use DB specific commands to get meta data.  Outside of what you get with a `desc <tablename>` you would be looking at some DB specific commands, which would not be very portable.

Comment: Can you share with us the DBMS?

Comment: this is using JDBC, the underlying database can by any database.

Answer (score 2):

Solved this by using a `PreparedStatement`. A `PreparedStatement` does not execute the statement.